# Programmatically enable GitHub Discussions for a repository

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a way to enable GitHub Discussions for a repository using the GitHub API? The only way to enable discussions that I could find is [manually](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/discussions/quickstart) through the Settings page.

Comment: After scouring the documentation and a Google search, there doesn't seem to be a way to enable GitHub Discussions through the REST API.

Comment: Yes, there is an ongoing [discussion](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/43) in the GitHub feedback repo about a possible future REST API for GitHub Discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub recently released the Discussions GraphQL API. The documentation for the API is available [here](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/using-the-graphql-api-for-discussions).

Answer (score 1):

With the [GitHub CLI gh v2.22.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.22.0) (Jan. 2023), you can do so using [`gh repo edit --enable-discussions[=false]`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit):

It enables/disables the discussion on your remote GitHub repository right from command-line.

That way, you don't have to directly manipulate the GH API: the API call is done for you through the API.